# How do you find the line perpendicular to $y=6$ passing through $(-1,6)$?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

A line has the equation $y = 6$. Find the perpendicular line that passes through $(-1,6)$.

$m1 = -1/m2$

$m1 = -1/0$

$m1$ = Math error

Isn't that how you find the second slope? I got math error on this one.

Comment: HINT: The answer is exactly inside your question.

Comment: An additional note: Have you thought of the question before asking? Tell us about what you have currently derived and your problems so that we can tackle them in a more efficient way. Moreover, you should use MathJax to type mathematical formulas or equations. Thank you for your corporation.

Comment: You might want to consider posting your attempt or the post will be voted to close

Comment: m1 = -1/m2. In this case, I got math error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$ y = 6 $ is a horizontal line, so a perpendicular line to it, is a vertical line, and vertical lines have the equation, $ x= a$.  Since the required line passes through $(-1, 6)$, then $a = -1$, hence the equation of the required line is

$$ x = -1 $$

Comment: In other words, you can solve this without using things like $m_1=-1/m_2$ which you barely understand.

Comment: Ha Ha Ha !! Very funny